# Can't seem to make the results of query to be unique

Tags: mysql, sql, join, unique, greatest-n-per-group

my problem is that I need to make the following statement only each drink (a.DRINK) once/unique but I can't seem to make it do so.

```sql
create table LOWEST as 
    select a.DRINK, min(b.PRICE), c.STREET, c.BLDG_NO
    from ALLDRINKS a
    left join SERVES b on a.DRINK = b.DRINK
    left join LOCATED c on b.PUB = c.PUB
    group by a.DRINK, c.STREET, c.BLDG_NO
```

Current Results i'm getting

```
------------------------------------------------
| DRINK |min(b.PRICE)|     STREET    | BLDG_NO |
| VODKA |    7.10    | FAKE ST.      |   123   |
| VODKA |    4.50    | OAK Ave.      |    13   | 
| VODKA |    8.30    | Rail RD.      |    11   | 
| RUM   |    6.30    | Cherry RD.    |   131   | 
| RUM   |   10.30    | TEST Pl.      |    21   |  
------------------------------------------------
```

where i'm expecting:

```
------------------------------------------------
| DRINK |min(b.PRICE)|     STREET    | BLDG_NO |
| VODKA |    4.50    | OAK Ave.      |    13   |  
| RUM   |    6.30    | Cherry RD.    |   131   |   
------------------------------------------------
```

If you could also explain the logic behind what needed to be done that'd be super helpful in the future! Thank you in advance!
-Using MYSQL Workbench 8.0

Comment: Could you please add some of the rows in your tables and the output you're currently getting? It would help a lot finding the answer :) Also see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Fixing now my bad

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: Your query gets the min(price)  by a.DRINK, c.STREET, c.BLDG_NO if you only want the min(price) by drink then drop  c.STREET, c.BLDG_NO  from the select and the group by.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question i've gone through and added/corrected details @Balastrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the row in `serves` that has the minimum price for each `drink`, along with the corresponding `location`. If so you should not think *aggregation*, but *filtering*.

You can use a correlated subquery for filtering in the `left join`:

```
create table lowest as 
select d.drink, s.price, c.street, l.bldg_no
from alldrinks d
left join serves s
    on  s.drink = d.drink
    and s.price = (select min(s1.price) from serves s1 where s1.drink = s.drink)
left join located l 
    on  l.pub = s.pub
```

Note that I renamed your table aliases so they are more meaningful, which makes the query easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` window function in the table `SERVES` to get the minimum price for each `DRINK`, so you don't need `group by`:

```
create table LOWEST as 
    select a.DRINK, b.PRICE, c.STREET, c.BLDG_NO
    from ALLDRINKS a
    left join (
      select t.* 
      from (
        select *, row_number() over (partition by DRINK order by price) rn
        from SERVES      
      ) t
      where t.rn = 1
    ) b on a.DRINK = b.DRINK
    left join LOCATED c on b.PUB = c.PUB
```